# Functions accepting smart pointers and references?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, smart-pointers

I have a mostly conceptual problem. In my code I have a few classes (let's call one of them `Foo` that I use in various contexts -- sometimes stack allocation, sometimes heap allocation (this usually with smart pointers). Let's consider this situation:

```
class Bar {
  public:
  void beep( ???(Foo) fooObject, int howManyTimes);
};
```

Now every time I write functions like beep I have to decide whether it should receive `const Foo &`, `std::shared_ptr<Foo>`, `std::unique_ptr<Foo>` etc. -- and, in many cases, I need the same logic implemented for more than one case.

I see a few possible solutions, none of them fully satisfactory:

- everything is a `shared_ptr` -- slower execution and boilerplate code in cases where stack allocation is more appropriate,
- no smart pointers -- a lot of additional code for manual deallocation,
- macro-generated variants of `beep` -- IDEs support it very poorly,
- manually generated variants of `beep` -- I want stay DRY, thank you,
- using `some_smart_ptr::get` -- probably the best solution as long as I don't need shared ownership, transfer of ownership nor threads.

What I would really like is a variant (something of comparable complexity) of the last option that is applicable in more situations.

Comment: Use whichever signature is *appropriate* for your problem. If the function takes unique ownership: unique pointer. If the function takes shared ownership: shared pointer. If the function only observes an existing object: reference.

Comment: A function shouldn't need to know whether a pointer is a smart pointer or not. Something wrong with your design otherwise.

Comment: @KerrekSB So, if the function only observes an object and I have a shared_ptr, I should use .get() instead of, e.g., a weak_ptr? It doesn't feel right (or at least not right enough).

Comment: @EJP how could it possibly not know? It's in the function's signature.

Comment: @KerrekSB Additionally, if the function only cares about the value of the argument: pass by value.

Comment: @matb: You use `*` :-)

Comment: @JosephMansfield: I'd modify that advice to "if the function only needs a mutable, private copy of the value, pass by value". I wouldn't want to encourage general copying of vectors and strings without good cause.

Comment: @Matb That's my point. It shouldn't be in the signature.

Comment: @KerrekSB It's really just personal preference, but I only use a const ref if I care about the identity of an object (hence reference) but don't need to modify it (hence `const`). I see the idea of "pass by const ref if you only care about the value but don't want to modify it/copy it" as a micro-optimisation. (This is an idea I've only adopted recently)

Comment: @KerrekSB it boils down to he same thing :). But I have no guarantee that the object will not be deallocated while the function is working on it (threads). I'm afraid it will bite me one day.

Comment: @matb I think it's safe to assume that any reference-taking function has an implied requirement on its callee: "The referenced object should be valid for the duration of the function"

Comment: @EJP could you provide an example (in C++)? As far as I know, this must be in the signature (unless you do dirty tricks with macros and templates).

Comment: You seem to be confused about what your program is doing. That's never a good thing. Build complex systems up from small, isolated, understandable parts and document/understand their interfaces. You should never have to *guess* whether something is alive.

Comment: @JosephMansfield right, it should be this way. My worry is that as far as I know "using my *" (as suggested by @KerrekSB) can violate this requirement.

Comment: @matb It's the calling code's responsibility to not pass around references to objects that might be destroyed in another thread while the references exist. If you need to ensure the lifetime of objects, you should be passing shared ownership, but this situation (dependency between threads) shouldn't come up too often - I'd argue that something is wrong in the design. Just think about your function argument types from the function's perspective - which is exactly what KerrekSB did.

Comment: @KerrekSB I just don't know what it will do in a few months. I want to avoid solutions that may cause problems, having a general idea of what I may want to do.

Comment: @JosephMansfield it sounds convincing, I'll keep this in mind while coding (and designing). Thank you.